# VW Remote Starter Retrofit

Tags: vw, key, remote-start

I have a 2007 VW Golf City (Canadian car based off of the MK IV platform with the 2.0L engine), and it's a fantastic little car. Has power windows, cruise control, rear window and mirror defrosters, etc! However, there's one thing I'm really missing: remote start. In Canadian winters, it's so nice to be able to heat up the engine before you enter the car.

So I'd like to retrofit a remote start. However, I don't want to get a non-VW key fob. Ideally, I'd like to get one of the VW key fobs that they have on new cars. Would it be possible to retrofit a remote start and use one of the new VW key fobs?

Otherwise, is it possible to have a little fob dedicated solely to remote start? Or even an app on my phone?

But ideally I'd like to use one of the new VW fobs. So is it possible and how would I go about it?

Comment: You would need a receiver capable of decoding the fob commands - either buy or make. Outside the scope of this site though.

Comment: @Solar Mike I figured it might be outside the scope of this site unfortunately... Any site you could suggest? Maybe a VW-specific forum?

Comment: A programming or coding stack - have you tried a vw forum...

Comment: Your best bet is to just get a VW remote start and put it in yourself. Without prior knowledge retrofitting a VW remote is insurmountable. There are 3 problems. Receive the signal at the required frequency. Decode the signal, meaning turn the radio waves into bits of data. Finally, decrypt the data turning those bits into something useful. The latter will be the hardest because if VW is at all smart they will use a rolling code system that you would have to break.

Comment: If you are okay with an extra key fob, most aftermarket kits contain a fob just for the remote start.  You could retain your original VW key.  Your keychain will get a little bigger, and your wallet a bit smaller.  This assumes you have an automatic transmission.  Forget about installing remote start on a stickshift.